# Visial Studio Project Icon Reset After Nuget Update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We have an internal Nuget package which includes an icon file which is used as the project icon.

When the Nuget package is updated the project icon is reset to the default icon.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

> When the Nuget package is updated the project icon is reset to the default icon.

That is because the update of the nuget package broken reference of the icon in the Visual Studio. We have to reset the icon after nuget package update.

> Is there anyway to prevent this?

A workaround to prevent this, you can separate the icon file from the package and then pack the icon as a separate package. In this case, the reference relationship will not be broken after the internal Nuget package update. After finishing the development, merge the icon to the internal Nuget package.

Comment: This is pretty much what I figured as Nuget uninstalls the old package before installing the new, I was just hoping there was a way to mark a file in Nuget to prevent it being removed/replaced if not different.

Comment: @apc, As far as I know the answer is negative. Because nugte manage the package as a whole. We could not handle the internal files in the package by nuget. So the workaround is separate the icon file from the package.